# KeePassXC 2.6.4 addons failure on Firefox and Chrome/Brave /Ubuntu 20.04 and 20.10

Tags: 20.04, 20.10, add-on, keepassxc

I wanted to use KeePassXC as my password manager, it has option to fill out login and password on saved passwords in KPXC database. Here what trouble I get:

> Cannot connect to KeePassXC. Check that browser integration is enabled in KeePassXC settings.

After reload button new info shows:

> Key exchange was not successful.

Beforehand I opened KeePassXC, unlocked database, changed setting for integration with browsers, did with Firefox and Brave on Ubuntu 20.04. I do not know why its not getting keys from KPXC, in both add-ons settings KPXC is showing ***No connected databases found.*** Trying to connect doesn't solve the issue. I want to use Yubikey5 with KeePassXC but if this add-on database connection still be failing, i will abandon KPXC and will look for other good utility that is compatible with Yubikey5.

Comment: where can i post it then? There is one topic about KeyPass and Browser issue here as well, and there were issues resolved. On Other system this issue with not passing keys database is non existent. Probably some failure in Ubuntu to transfer data to browsers add-ons?

Comment: It worked for me. It is difficult to debug from a distance what might go wrong on your end, but I don't suspect a bug. Also with the browser plugin,you need to KeePassXC open anyway. For this reason, I find it equally convenient (or inconvenient) to use the Global Type feature instead of the browser plugins. In the browser with the cursor on the login field, press Ctrl+Shift+A, and KeypassXC will autofill username and password.

Comment: Are you using the snap version (which for me on 20.10 shows v2.6.4) or the package version (which for me on 20.10 shows v2.6.1). I use the package version 2.6.1 and no problem for me with Firefox and Chrome. Note that in KeePassXC settings under Browser Integration it does say `Browsers installed as snaps are currently not supported.` so are your browsers installed as snaps or packages? If snaps then that will probably be why.

Comment: I am using package version 2.6.4 which i installed by Discover. I do not know how my Brave is installed as snap or not, but Firefox was native since installation. How to check what version of KPXC i have? Or how should I install not snapped version?

Comment: Run `snap list` on command line to list installed snaps. I don't use Discover but I think you can choose the source where available as per this article: https://userbase.kde.org/Discover

Answer (score 2):

Issue occurred because snap version of KeePassXC and Brave browser.
To install unsnapped KeePassXC version:
Add PPA to system's software source:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phoerious/keepassxc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install keepassxc
```

unsnapped version of Brave browser:

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl gnupg
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brave-browser
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it. It's worth noting for others who may see this in future that you would only need to add the ppa if you wanted/needed to install the latest version of KeePassXC. Ubuntu has a packaged version by default that can be installed via `apt` or the software store, it just may not be the latest version at any time.

Comment: I was stupefied at first, what happened that it didn't work. Codlord, could you explain me, why they add snap versions in software store or via apt? Snap versions are heavy, could posses altered source code and may not work well and be cause of many issues. The alternation of source code is most stunning to me. Today was my first time with facing snap problem which astounded me... I do hope other people in future won't make same mistake as me thanks to this post.

Comment: This is not the place for discussion and I am sure snaps have advantages but the main source of issues seems to be because snaps are sandboxed. I don't think snaps are a problem as such but most users (myself included) do not really understand the differences good/bad or otherwise and Ubuntu software stores do not help themselves by largely hiding the source (or at least not making it clear what the source is) as well as not making it clear why a user may want snap vs non-snap.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happens to me with the flatpak version.

Using:

```
sudo apt install keepassxc
```

and enabling browser integration again works for me.